# How to customize mat-select dropdown position?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Its been couple of days since i have not found the solution for this. As there is an option for mat-menu that is overlaptrigger property but there is no property to perform this in mat select dropdown. Is there any way to customize the mat-select dropdown position by overriding the css or any better solution.

Comment: hey, i got the same issue, i'm looking into the `panelClass` option of `mat-select`, but, i cannot find any solution... you did?

Comment: @Flow It's actually just `class`.

Comment: have you found a solution please?

Comment: @nour sorry there are way arounds but not an exact solution so we are still waiting for angular on this but instead of this you can use below links

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Answer (score 79):

```
<mat-select placeholder="Language" disableOptionCentering panelClass="myPanelClass">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let locale of locales" [value]="locale">
        {{locale}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Utilize **disableOptionCentering** and **panelClass** like I have above. Then within your **styles.scss** reference your panelClass and do

```
.myPanelClass{
    margin-top: 30px !important; 
}
```

This worked for me. Note that the scss **must be in your styles.scss not your component's scss file**. You might not need to use important here, I have other classes around this so I did use it.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Important is not necessary as you described. It's also possible from the local style-file with ```::ng-deep```

Comment: @Marius I noticed using `::ng-deep` as the first layer in component css introduce some strange behavior, at least using `ng serve`, which a global style is only applied upon this component load. So you might notice different style before and after loading this component if some other elements are affected by this global style. So now I always prepend `:host` in front, but then that won't work in this case.

Comment: Remember to put that class in `styles.css` as buttons are created in overlay which is outside the component.

Comment: i tried putting both disableOptionCentering and panelClass but i could not find the panelClass while inspecting the element. What could be the problem?

Comment: @KimHonoridez did you add this to the styles.css?

Comment: disableOptionCentering fixed the weird behavior I was experiencing with my select panel positioning. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 14):

I've found the solution as **disableOptionCentering** directive for **mat-select**, so after using this dropdaown can be customized.

from timmoy:
https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/9885

Example usage:

```
<mat-select
    [(ngModel)]="currentPokemon"
    [required]="pokemonRequired" 
    [disabled]="pokemonDisabled" 
    #pokemonControl="ngModel" 
    disableOptionCentering>
<mat-option 
    *ngFor="let creature of pokemon" 
    [value]="creature.value">
{{ creature.viewValue }}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 8):

I am using Angular. I have used the same property and it works fine with `panelClass`. But I used it this way `[disableOptionCentering]="true"`

Answer (score 6):

try updating

```
.cdk-overlay-pane  { 
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:auto;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  z-index:1000;
  display:flex;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  transform:none !important; 
  margin-top:22px;
}
```

which is in @angular\material\prebuilt-themes\indigo-pink.css.

added transform:none !important; margin-top:22px; which is working well for me.

Comment: Good solution but it messes up the positioning of auto-complete dropdowns.

Answer (score 5):

//Add this

```
.mat-select-panel-wrap{
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
}

.mat-select-panel-wrap .mat-select-panel{
    min-width: calc(100% + 12px) !important;
    transform: translateX(4px) !important
}
```

//Change 26px, 12px and 4px to what suit you.