# Position Mat-Select options ONLY below trigger element

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm working on an Angular 8 project, using Material. I've searched SO and google for solutions on how to what I want, but my search has been futile.

I also went through [How to customize mat-select dropdown position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983954/how-to-customize-mat-select-dropdown-position) but my question is different. That question seems to be more about the **position** of the popover. The solutions there are about **positioning the menu below or above but not over the trigger element**

I guess, my question is more about the **direction** of the popover. I would like **to only drop down and not drop up**. I don't know if, I'm making enough sense here...lol

**Current Behavior:** 
When a user opens the `mat-select` it pops up the options 1. Over the element (like somehow in the middle). 2. It positions the rest of the options either above or below the element, depending on the scroll position (or rather element's position on screen).

**The Problem right now: When it pops up above the element, the options are getting rendered out side the screen.**

**Wanted Behavior:**
When user clicks the mat-select, 1. it pops up options BELOW the element. 2. Despite the element position, options are ALWAYS show below. Like a dropdown, never a drop up.
Sort of like how you can choose to use a dropdown or drop up with [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

Thank you in advance for you assistance and suggestions.

Comment: Só you want to provide your user a bad ux? If the dropdown is on bottom of screen he will not be able to choose options. Hmm...

Comment: Lol, of course not. In the situation where I'm using it, it's the first element, on screen, and options are popping up, right out of the screen (at the top)

Comment: I dont think so its a good approach to change that position which are by default as they change the value on runt time. I also need that but didnt find any work around so adjust what it is by default

Comment: Thank you @Awais for the input. I guess I was so used to the Bootstrap UI, where one can choose to have a dropdown or drop-up. Will continue to think of better solutions

Comment: Yes but the thing is, its components are paid the one which i need so that's why i prefer angular material without bootstrap. but i thing this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983954/how-to-customize-mat-select-dropdown-position

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize mat-select dropdown position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983954/how-to-customize-mat-select-dropdown-position)

Comment: @Awais thank you again for sharing that valuable information. I have gone through it, and unfortunately it still does not cover what I want, but it is the closest I've seen so far.

Comment: Ops anyway glad to hear that it is closest one because its also mention on git-hub with above link approach https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13426