# Open Angular Material Autocomplete(mat-autocomplete) Always Under Input

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

How can I Open Angular Material Autocomplete(mat-autocomplete) always in bottom of Input?
Is there any position config? or I must use CSS tricks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize mat-select dropdown position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983954/how-to-customize-mat-select-dropdown-position)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the matAutocompletePositionto attribute your input element.

`<Input matAutocompletePosition="below">`

[SAMPLE](https://inglkruiz.github.io/angular-material-reusable-autocomplete/)

Comment: Angular Material Doc:
https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocompleteTrigger