# How to set the position of the mat-select-panel to be always below

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select

How to set the position of the mat-select-panel to be always below ? Dropdown height is not constant so I can’t set the const margin for the panel class

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983954/how-to-customize-mat-select-dropdown-position

Comment: Unfortunately not. The solution here is helpful when dropdown panel has const height. In my case I have dropdown with chips. If I select few items then row is wrapped and the height changes dynamically. So the panel margin should also adjust dynamically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.